# Other linker flag -ObjC caused "Symbol not found" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a pure Objective-C project which structures like this

- Custom static library linked to App target and Today extension target, used for sharing/reusing code
- Static library contains `AFNetworking` library installed by CocoaPods (with use_frameworks! disabled)
- iOS today extension contains `Masonry` library installed by CocoaPods (with use_frameworks! disabled)
  [image]

When installing `Masonry` to today extension, CocoaPods adds `-ObjC` to Other Linker Flag in my today extension target, which will cause a `Undefined symbol` error when compiling extension target.

[image]

However, if I remove the `-ObjC` flag, the project will compile successfully, I have no idea of how this happens. I've search through the internet, the only thing I know is that `-ObjC` flag will

> Causes the linker to load every object file in the library that
>   defines an Objective-C class or category

But I don't know why this behavior ends up a compile error.

This is a test projected I've created to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/JohnnyTseng/SimpleProject

The project will now result in a "Undefined symbol" compile error, but if you remove the

- `${inherited}`
- `-ObjC`

flag from the `SimpleTodayExtension`, it will compile with no error

[image]

Although the project compiles fine with `-ObjC` flag removed, but I am very curious of what has happened behind scene, it will be appreciated if someone can teach me how it happened, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From `clang` [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)

> ```
> -ObjC
> Treat source input files as Objective-C inputs
>
> -ObjC++
> Treat source input files as Objective-C++ inputs
> ```

This is explicit commands, if they absent, compiler detects used language implicitly, usually by file extension. So if to follow, as usal, *.m, *.c, *.cpp then all is OK, what actually you observe.

Comment: But my source files in my custom static library are Objective-C, I still don't understand why this will lead to a compiler error? Could you explain further more? Thank you for helping!

Comment: fix typo: *compile